# Swift 3 - ! vs ? for optional function parameters

Tags: swift, swift3

In Swift 3, when one has optional function parameters, what is the difference between functions with:

```
func doThis(num: Int!)
```

and

```
func doThat(num: Int?)
```

Comment: Not a Swift expert, but doesn't ! unwrap an optional and ? is an optional?

Comment: You should have googled that before posting this stuff to this forum. It's not a very difficult query. Optional means you can expect a nil but with ! You need to pass something in its unwrapped state which it will crash if a nil is passed

Comment: My question is about the function declaration.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari: I don't think it will necessarily crash. It will only crash if unwrapped. If you pass it on to something that can handle optionals, `nil` will work fine.

Comment: @Thilo Yes right. Once it is accessed/used, then it will crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both declare that `num` is an optional `Int`.

If you do `Int!` it can be implicitly unwrapped inside of your function.
That means you can use it in places where a plain (non-optional) `Int` is required. In that case, it will fail if it happens to be `nil`.

With a "proper" `Int?` the compiler will not let you use `num` where an `Int` is required and forces you to include a check/guard first.

The `Int!` construct is mostly there for interoperability with Objective-C code where it is not clear if a reference type is optional or not. You should avoid it in new code.

Comment: Yes, this is in line with the behavior I observe. Thanks.